# img-responsive not scaling properly a set of imgs

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to set a responsive behavior to a set of images displayed horizontally and centered in a (single) container, but I cannot find the way to do it. Obviously just setting "img-responsive" to each img without an independent container for everyone will not work, since the responsiveness is based on the width of the container.

This is how it looks: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/W5kE3JsN4e).

In the example there's only 3 images (random icons), but there could be many more, that's why my interest in scaling.

I tried setting a container for every image, with a width of 20% (fixed height, since I want them to scale horizontally), and adding the img-responsive class, but they still don't scale a little. Check it [here](http://www.bootply.com/IDq7UbRB4s).

Do you guess which might be the problem in the second Bootply? And probably a better approach?

Thank you.

Comment: `.img-responsive` won't scale up, only down.

Comment: As Gavin mentioned, `.img-responsive` can only scale to the original size of the image. If you need it to be larger you must have a larger source image.

Comment: Actually I do want to scale them down. This looks like I'm doing something completely wrong, then haha...

Comment: okay, I got it, the div was bigger than the img itself, so I have to make it equal to or smaller to it...